# Fragments don't communicate via sharedViewModel and LiveData

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-livedata

I want first fragment to observe information via LiveData comming from second fragment. I tried doing the same but only in 1 Fragment and it worked, but as soon as I want to recieve the data in other fragment it stops working (textView has no text). How should I fix this problem?

SharedViewModel:

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val selected : MutableLiveData<Person> = MutableLiveData<Person>()

    fun select(person: Person){
        selected.value = person
    }

    fun getSelected(): LiveData<Person>{
        return selected
    }
}
```

First fragment:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        sharedViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)

        sharedViewModel.getSelected().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
            textView.text = it.name
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Second Fragment:

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        sharedViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_dashboard)

        val person = Person("John")
        val newPerson = Person("Anton")

        val button2: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.button2)
        val button: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.button)

        button2.setOnClickListener {
            sharedViewModel.select(person)
        }

        button.setOnClickListener {
            sharedViewModel.select(newPerson)
        }
        return root
    }
}
```

Class Person:

```
class Person (var name: String) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders#of(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) but instead you should be using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders#of(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity). That's how sharing works.